# C# query to MySql database doesn't return all columns

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

The issue that I'm having is that I'm using a very simple MySql query in C# to return data to a table. However, it only returns 3 of 4 columns.

The select statement is:

```
"SELECT * FROM workorder.forecast"
```

The database table has 4 columns:
id  |  forecast  |  foredate  |  plant

When I run the query in MySQL Workbench it outputs just fine. However, somehow, the code below drops the 'foredate' column when queried through C#. So the data in the outputted table is everything except for the entire 'foredate' column.

Here's my C#:

```
DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();

using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["workorderConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM workorder.forecast";

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        returnTable.Load(reader);
    }
}

GridView1.DataSource = returnTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I've tried calling the columns in the SELECT statement instead of using the star(*), but had the same results. This code I'm posting is actually a really stripped down version of this where I pretty much removed everything I could to try and troubleshoot.

I'm at a loss here and I haven't been able to find any other posts relating to this issue.

Comment: Are you certain that you ran the query verbatim in MySQL?

Comment: Did you check if your connectionstring is working against the correct database?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :: Yes, just to be sure I just tried copying and pasting again from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @Steve :: I did check this. All of the other fields return correctly as well, it is just this one column that doesn't return.

Comment: Have you checked your data bindings? I'd suggest using the debugger and stick a breakpoint after returnTable.Load(reader) and verified if has 4 columns.

Comment: How are the columns on the GridView being setup? Autogenerated or did you define them? I'm wondering if the column is just missing from the GridView but your DataTable has all the right columns.

Comment: @peval27 :: Good thought. Just did this and discovered that the returnTable Datatable does have all four columns in it.

Comment: @rmc00 :: This does seem to be the case after trying peval's suggestion. The Gridview is being autogenerated.

Comment: it's the grid. focus there.

Comment: is **workorder** a table and **forecast** a column?

Comment: @RamgyBorja: The 'workorder.forecast' call refers to the mysql Schema and table. With mysql (and sql) you say SELECT [columns] FROM [schema].[table], the ' * ' in place of specific columns tells it to select all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After noting that the datatable I was using to populate my Gridview did have the column in it, I spent some time trying to figure out why I was losing the column when binding the data.

I assume it has something to do with the datetime format, but I was unable to figure out why.

I did however figure out a work around with my SELECT statement. I changed it to the following, to convert the datetime field to a varchar:

```
SELECT id, forecast, DATE_FORMAT(foredate, '%m-%d-%Y') as foredate, plant FROM workorder.forecast
```

After doing that, the column now appears in the gridview.